# Sorting a file by multiple columns using bash sort

Tags: bash, sorting

Here is the file I am working with

```
word01.2    10  25
word01.2    30  50
word01.1    10  30
word01.1    40  50
word01.2    40  50
word01.1    10  20
word01.1    5   8
```

When I try my sort command

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 file.txt
```

I receive the following; I don't understand why line 2 and line 1 are not sorted, they should be in reverse positions

```
word01.1    10  30
word01.1    10  20
word01.1    40  50
word01.1    5   8
word01.2    10  25
word01.2    30  50
word01.2    40  50
```

When I try to add -g to the sort, the sorted file has more problems and column 1 is no longer sorted

```
sort -k1,1 -gk2,2 -gk3,3 file.txt 
word01.1    5   8
word01.1    10  20
word01.2    10  25
word01.1    10  30
word01.2    30  50
word01.1    40  50
word01.2    40  50
```

What I would like as results is

```
word01.1    5   8
word01.1    10  20
word01.1    10  30
word01.1    40  50
word01.2    10  25
word01.2    30  50
word01.2    40  50
```

Comment: Lines 1 and 2 *should* be in the correct position according to the command you give; the other out-of-order lines are, as others have pointed out, due to sorting as strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the [`-n`/`--numeric-sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-numeric-sort) option, to sort according to string numerical value, not lexicographically (at least for second and third field):

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n file.txt
word01.1    5   8
word01.1    10  20
word01.1    10  30
word01.1    40  50
word01.2    10  25
word01.2    30  50
word01.2    40  50
```

Note that you can provide a global `-n` flag, to sort all fields as numerical values, or per key. Format for key is `-k KEYDEF`, where `KEYDEF` is `F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]` and `OPTS` is one or more of *ordering options*, like `n` (numerical), `r` (reverse), `g` (general numeric), `h` (human numeric), etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can also combine fields 2-3 in one KEYDEF, e.g.

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,3n file
```

**Output**

```
word01.1    5   8
word01.1    10  20
word01.1    10  30
word01.1    40  50
word01.2    10  25
word01.2    30  50
word01.2    40  50
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer

```
 $ sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n file.txt
```

provided by randomir is correct in every case.

Below mentioned combined option pasted by David C. Randin doesn't work corectly because it compare only first digit in third column.

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,3n file
```

I.e. below pasted file won't be sorted correctly:

```
word01.2    10  25
word01.2    30  50
word01.1    10  30
word01.1    40  50
word01.2    40  50
word01.1    10  20
word01.1    5   8
word01.1    410  50
word01.1    45  120
word01.1    45  100
word01.1    45  1000
word01.1    40  6
```

I recommend first option.